# Links inside Bootstrap list-group with title and tooltip shake bottom content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Any suggestions to fix this content shake? If I delete `title="1"` from `a` element shake will disappear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" href="TEST.ASP" class="list-group-item" title="1">First item</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    TEST
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add margin bottom 0 to the first child of the list, check the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.list-group-item:first-child {
 margin-bottom:0; 
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" href="TEST.ASP" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="list-group-item" title="1">First item</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    TEST
</div>

</body>
</html>
```